# I can't get the reducer to change state. That could be happening?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The dispatch data arrives at the reducer, through a Console.log, but the initialstate is maintained.
I want to do it without using redux but it doesn't work, with Context and useReducer, only

fichier App.js

```jsx
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { router } from "./router";
import { AuthProvider } from "./authpage/AuthContext";
import { AuthReducer, initialState } from "./authpage/AuthReducer";

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider initialState={initialState} AuthReducer={AuthReducer}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Fichier AuthContext

```jsx
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ AuthReducer, initialState, children }) => {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={useReducer(AuthReducer, initialState)}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

call from loginSigin

```jsx
import { register } from "./authActions";

import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";
import { types } from "../types";

export const LoginSignIn = () => {

 const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AuthContext);
  const registerSubmit = async () => {
    const body = await register(registerName, registerEmail, registerPassword);

    body.user
      ? dispatch({ type: types.AUTH_REGISTER, payload: body.user })
      : dispatch({ types: types.AUTH_ERROR, payload: body.msg });

    console.log(body);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>FORM</h1>

      <form submit={registerSubmit}>
        <buttton submit={registerSubmit}></buttton>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

The register function works and the console.log shows me this

```js
{ok: false, msg: 'El usuario ya existe'}
```

and I send it to dispatch
and I send it to the reducer with the dispatch

and finally it goes to reducer:

AuthReducer.js.

I hope that it reaches type , `types.AUTH_ERROR` and that the state changes but the initialstate always appears

```jsx
import { types } from "../types";
export const initialState = {
  checking: true,
  uid: null,
  user: null,
  msg: null,
};

export const AuthReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action.payload);
  console.log(action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case types.AUTH_REGISTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        checking: false,
      };
    case types.AUTH_ERROR:
      console.log("estos es");
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
        msg: action.payload,
        checking: false,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The response reaches the end, to the reducer, but once there, the state does not change.

Comment: Is there an error in your code snippet for `LoginSignIn`? I don't see `useContext` invoked anywhere

Comment: It was invoked, I didn't put it in. I forgot to write it . i put:                                                 
                                       const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AuthContext);

Comment: I found the error, in the error dispatch, of loginSigin, I have put 'types:' instead of 'type':

Comment: `<form submit={registerSubmit}><buttton submit={registerSubmit}></buttton></form>` looks very wrong. Chances are that when you hit the button, the form is submitted and whole page is reloading, the JS doesn't have a chance to do anything